# Estimating vector scalars to approach another vector

Tags: python, math, computer-science, heuristics

I have three vectors scaled by a, b and c respectively. How can I get an estimation of a, b and c so that the sum of the vectors is closest to a fourth vector?
[image: Here is an example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Numpy. The `solve()` function is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np

from numpy.linalg import solve

A = np.array([[4,11,9],[6,5,7],[3,5,9]])
B = np.array([3,8,5])
X = solve(A,B)

print(A)
print(B)
print(X)
```

The output should be:

```
[[ 4 11  9]
 [ 6  5  7]
 [ 3  5  9]]
[3 8 5]
[ 1.28723404 -0.54787234  0.43085106]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three equations, if you read your example line by line.

```
a*4 + b*11 + c*9 = 2
a*6 + b*5 + c*7 = 8
a*3 + b*5 + c*9 = 5
```

Then you can easily solve for each variable

```
a = (2 - b*11 - c*9) / 4
b = (8 - a*6 - c*7) / 5
b = (8 - ((2 - b*11 - c*9) / 4)*6 - c*7) / 5
b*5 + b*16.5 = 8 - 3  - c*13.5 - c*7
b = (8 - 3  - c*13.5 - c*7) / 21.5
a = (2 - ((8 - 3  - c*13.5 - c*7) / 21.5)*11 - c*9) / 4
```

now you can solve c with the last equation. When you have c use its value in the last two equations of a&b to solve for them.